# crontab being saved in tmp/ in debian

Tags: cron, debian

I'm trying to make a crontab with crontab -e, but it saves it in `tmp/crontab.FTt6nI/crontab`

the crons don't work so I guess that's the problem. But I don't understand why.

Comment: You misunderstand the output on screen. The command saves a temp file in the above path and will make changes in crontab once you saved and quit with your favorite text editor (e.g. vi)

Comment: alright thanks that's what I wanted to know

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197506/14334 also answered the same question

Answer (score 4):

type:

```
crontab -l
```

to show list of crontab, your newly added crontab should be on the list. you could set the crontab to email the output to you by > youremail@aaa.com, in this way you can assure the cronjob is already run.

example:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/cron.php > aaa@aaa.com
```

**make sure** the crond is running:

```
/etc/init.d/crond status
```

if it down, start it (centos/rhel):

```
/etc/init.d/crond start
```

debian/ubuntu:

```
/etc/init.d/cron start
```

hope that help.