# does $crontab -e eventually updates /etc/crontab?

Tags: cron

I'm digging along CRON and scheduling. 
I setup a scheduled job to fire every minute via `$crontab -e` + editing the file (weirdly named "/tmp/crontab.vst6TX/crontab")

My understanding is that `$crontab -e` opens A crontab... and that cron.d, the daemon, picks up the crontab and APPENDS the cron job within to the (systemwide) /etc/crontab. (as per comment from [crontab being saved in tmp/ in debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474063/crontab-being-saved-in-tmp-in-debian))

I'm watching the cron job fire every minute - yet I can't see it being added to the /etc/crontab job list... why? `$crontab -l` does show the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crontab -e` and `crontab -l` are to edit and display (respectively) the **current** user's crontab file (which are physically located in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`).  Therefore, each user can have their own separate crontab file in that directory.  So when you ran `crontab -e` and added a cron line, you ran `crontab -l` as the same user presumably, and therefore saw the line you added.

`/etc/crontab` is a completely different file.  You are correct, it is systemwide -- notice that the cron lines in that file specify a user.  The same is true for files in `/etc/cron.d`, the cron lines in the files will specify a user.

Oh and also, the `.d` suffix in `cron.d` does not refer to daemon.  Check this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/what-does-the-d-stand-for-in-directory-names) out.